# To scroll UIScrollView programmatically but don't handle only this action in delegate methods?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiscrollview, delegates

In my class I wrote the following delegate methods:

```
scrollViewDidScroll:
scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:
```

Then for this `scrollView` I use the following code:

```
scrollView.frame = ...;
scrollView.contentSize = ...;
[scrollView setContentOffset:... animated:NO];
```

The code and delegates work in a main thread but asynchronously to each other.

The problem is I don't want to call the described delegate methods with this code and. How to solve this issue? I can't simply write:

```
BOOL shouldCallDelegate = YES; //or NO
```

because I have other pieces of code which should be handled via these delegate methods.

**UPDATED**

I tried something like this:

```
NSLog(@"isMainThread == %d", [NSThread isMainThread]);
NSLog(@"isScrollViewBusy == %d", self.isScrollViewBusy);
self.isScrollViewBusy = YES;
scrollView.frame = ...;
scrollView.contentSize = ...;
[scrollView setContentOffset:... animated:NO];
self.isScrollViewBusy = NO;
```

Then in my delegate method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

   NSLog(@"isMainThread2 == %d", [NSThread isMainThread]);
   NSLog(@"isScrollViewBusy2 == %d", self.isScrollViewBusy);
   ...
}
```

You think that the app must write something like this?

```
isMainThread == 1
isScrollViewBusy == 0
isMainThread2 == 1
isScrollViewBusy2 == 0
```

In most cases it is so but when you try to rotate the screen:

```
isMainThread == 1
isScrollViewBusy == 0
isMainThread2 == 1
isScrollViewBusy2 == 1
```

So all the code is in the main thread but suddenly the first part of code is **suspended?!** somewhere between YES and NO while the app is processing the rotation and the delegate method is unexpectedly called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
id<UIScrollViewDelegate> delegate = scrollView.delegate;
scrollView.delegate = nil;
// do your stuff
scrollView.delegate = delegate
```

Comment: It is even worse than adding an additional `BOOL` variable because for example it disables the whole delegate. In other cases both solutions look like the same - they disable the calling of delegate from ALL the pieces of code

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov Delegate is disabled only for `//do your stuff` code. You said all calls to delegate happen in the main thread, thus there is no way for another piece of code to call delegate while you `//do your stuff`

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov And this solution is better than `BOOL` variable, because it does not pollute the code with unnecessary variables

Comment: I can't understand what happens but I logged `isMainThread` and `shouldCallDelegate`. I edited my question to show this strange behavior

Comment: when are you executing `[scrollView setContentOffset:... animated:NO];`?

Comment: between setting YES and NO. I still can't understand how it works. Why does it work normally when a device is not rotated?

Answer (score 0):

The only improvement I found is if offset is less than 1 then I think that a scroll view is still not scrolled so I don't perform actions on this event.

It doesn't solve the problem completely but it appears much more rarely.